# Событие скасания вне View

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-customview

У меня есть кастомный View на котором я отображаю какие либо данные, и мне нужно при касании любой точки вне этого View получить об этом информацию и перестать отображать информацию. Но я не знаю как получить информацию об касании вне View.

Comment: Сделай фоновый View, который и будет улавливать касания..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант использовать [View.OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener) - получили фокус при касаниях - отобразили "данные", потеряли фокус при касаниях вне - удалили.

Comment: для меня это решение не работает, OnFocusChangeListener просто не вызывается. Для проверки я в слушателе прописал логи, но они не выводились.

Comment: попробуйте добавить android:focusable="true"

Comment: я прописал setFocusable(true) перед установкой слушателя, это все равно не работает

Comment: Протестировал. Нужно добавить в конструкторе setClickable( true ); setFocusableInTouchMode( true ); слушатель нужно просто перегрузить onFocusChanged , работает но с ограничениями: фокус должен куда-то уходить а не все элементы могут его принять, например кнопки, корневой элемент можно заставить принимать фокус если в xml поставить аналогичные выше указанные атрибуты.

Comment: да, теперь заработало, спасибо